# Drawing of a Christian helping his own assailant

Tags: history, art

A few years back I saw a drawing of a Christian priest helping his own assailant to get up.
It was on a wiki page that I cannot remember.

I am hoping that some one here knows the page, and maybe even know a longer story behind that drawing.

Comment: There's some meta history on allowing these kinds of questions: [Should we accept "Help me find this thing" questions?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3766) and [Are we now allowing "shopping questions"?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3951) Seems like the community is okay with them.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. The community here usually prefers academically focused questions, so that might explain the downvote. I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: I understand. Question like this makes the site unprofessional.

Comment: randomA, I un-deleted this.  It's actually on-topic IMO for reasons explained [here](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4083/are-we-allowing-shopping-questions-or-not/4086#4086), and someone else had already voted to un-delete.  The biggest recommendation I'd give, however, is that if you''re going to post a "help me find this" question, please try to include as much detail as possible.

Comment: Is the drawing in Flimzy's post the actual one you remember or just similar?

Comment: @fredsbend, from what I can remember, it is what I was looking for.

Comment: @randomA: Then it was a bit of a lucky guess on my part, but I'm glad we could be of help! And welcome to the site!

Comment: Related is when John Paul II visited his would be assassin in prison.

Comment: I asked questions like this "only if necessary"

Comment: I think it was pretty early that the selfish stamp was applied without understanding real selfishness or am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are likely many drawings of similar content, but I suspect by far the most famous one is this drawing of [Dirk Willems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Willems), which was published in the book [Martyrs Mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyrs_Mirror) in 1685.

[image]

It illustrates the true story of Dirk Willems who had escaped from prison (where he was being persecuted for his faith), but when his persuer broke through some thin ice, Dirk turned around to rescue his persuer, only to be taken back into custody then killed for his faith in 1569.

Comment: This story has a *Les Miserables* feel to it.

Comment: @fredsbend: Considering that *Les Misérables* was published nearly 200 years later, I'd say that it has a *Martyrs Mirror* feel to it :)

Comment: Or that it actually as a Paul feel to it, considering he stayed in the prison, saving the lives of the centurions.

Comment: @fredsbend: Ah, but that has a Gospel feel to it, considering that Jesus died so that *his* persecutors could live! ;)

Comment: @Flimzy I bow to your superior reasoning.

Comment: I don't mean to nitpick, but this is a _lithograph_, not a drawing.

Comment: @Andrew: I think you do mean to nitpick. It's also not a lithograph. It's a JPEG file representing an image, which was scanned, likely from a lithographic reproduction of a drawing.

Comment: @flimzy Bam! got me.